# How do raid controllers determine which disk is faulty?

Tags: raid

So it occurred to me that using XOR parity I cannot determine which disk is faulty in a stripe set.

Assume that one of the disks in the set is silently flipping bits on the platters(aka bit rot),say for example due to bad firmware. The disk is not failing or reporting bad blocks, but it occasionally commits to disk something else than it was input.

Using XOR, like any other checksum, will not say which disk in the stripe was the cause of the bad parity calculation, but you know one of the disks has a problem.

This scenario must be solved some how, given the constraints of raid 5, but honestly it eludes me. I can imagine that raid-6 with horizontal (raid-4'ish) and diagonal parity can triangulate the bad blocks and show what disk contained the bad area.... but this question pertains to raid-5 sets.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What type of RAID exactly?  The answer to that question determines how a bad disk is detected or if its even possible for it to be detected.  The more specific information you provide the better answer can give

Comment: well any raid scheme that uses XOR would in theory be impacted, but for the sake of example... let's just assume standard raid-5 configuration, but you may also go with raid-4 if that works.

Comment: RAID 4 and RAID 5 use parity bits.  If I drive has bad parity bits its considered bad.

Comment: That is correct, the parity is an XOR calculation. computing the parity can reveal that A) no porblem, or B) there is a problem, but does not reveal which of the members of the stripe set had the problem.

Comment: Most drives have an internal checksum method.  'Bit rot' as you call seems like it should result in a checksum failure on the drive with the bit rot.  Also, firmware failures are very rare.  Physical problems on disk are the most common problem.  RAID5 simply isn't perfect.  There could be cases where it would simply be impossible for the RAID controller to know.

Comment: zoredache, do modern disks maintain a checksum table for all the blocks on the disk? Or perhaps just what is on the internal cache, during write operations? It occurs to me that an XOR parity scheme is fundamentally vulnerable to bitrot, as described, so some other way of detecting faults must be put to use. Perhaps the checksum on write, but that only helps the short term. I'm guessing the raid controller attempts to relocate a stripe, then runs a write & read test to the blocks of disk interdependently, but that is massively inefficient. so much so it had not occurred to me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A RAID controller determines which disk is faulty by seeing which one is throwing I/O errors or is not responding.

A modern hard drive (ie. one made in the past 20 years or so) uses sector-level ECC to spot and correct bit-flip errors.  The ECC systems currently in use can correct any single-bit error in a sector, and can spot all double-bit errors.  If repeated reads of a sector consistently produce single-bit errors, the drive firmware will silently re-map the sector to an unused part of the drive (all modern hard drives have a bit of spare space for this purpose); if double-bit errors are produced, the firmware will report an I/O error to the controller, and a RAID controller will mark the drive as failed.  In order for data to be corrupted undetectably, at least three bits in a single sector need to flip -- an event that is vanishingly rare.

If you suspect bad firmware is causing bit flips, you can spot this at the RAID level (for RAID 1, 10, 5, and 6) by running a consistency check, but this will just tell you that there are stripes where the parity/mirroring doesn't match; it won't tell you which drive is bad.  You can find the bad drive by pulling a drive from the array and running a "surface scan" for bad blocks with your favorite disk-checking tool: if the firmware is bad, the scan should find hundreds of thousands of bad sectors.